# Does golang version 1.6.2 contain a Trojan?

Tags: trojan

I am trying to install [the current stable version](https://golang.org/dl/) of [golang](https://golang.org/) (version 1.6.2). However, [Kaspersky says it contains the Trojan Ebowla](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9c853bbb54734ddc54c1d57f6315724deb1a3878a3c0ad36b6fdc0e14a7be300/analysis/1467834510/).

Is this a false positive or is there really a problem with the golang?

Comment: For reference: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9c853bbb54734ddc54c1d57f6315724deb1a3878a3c0ad36b6fdc0e14a7be300/analysis/1467834510/

Comment: I would take this up with the golang team by filing a bug at https://github.com/golang/go/issues. Validate the signature (SHA256) of the download to ensure that you downloaded the correct MSI package.

Comment: It is the correct msi file and is signed by Google. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16292) with the golang team.